# User has changed his name in the active directory and wants see his mysite with the new URL

Tags: 2007, administration, backup, architecture, my-site

Question : 
User has changed his name in the active directory and wants see his mysite with the new URL.

Can we follow the steps given below: 
    ○ Take the backup of the existing site collection (Stsadm -o export)
    ○ Goto SSP -> User profile -> remove Personal site URL -> Save
    ○ Ask her to click on the "Mysite" Link
    ○ New site collection will be created for her
    ○ Import the old collection content (Stsadm -o import)
    ○ you may need to change the site title of the new site collection after the import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did exactly as you suggested and it worked in my test environment. So I guess you have the right approach. It was not production so you should check with your user before making any changes.

I hope this helps :)